# On the central limit theorem

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, central-limit-theorem

The Central Limit Theorem states for a sequence of i.i.d. random variables $\{X_i\}$, 
$$\frac{\overline{X} - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} \to N(0,1)$$
in distribution as $n \to \infty$. I saw in some lecture notes that this implies
$$\overline{X} \to N\left(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\right).$$
But does that statement make any sense? The right side is a function of $n$. What let's us move the $\sqrt{n}$ and derive this implication? I can see it heuristically and how it can be used in statistics exercises (use a large value of $n$).

Comment: I believe you multiply by $\sqrt n$ rather than divide.

Comment: I guess they just meant $\bar{X}\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$

Comment: @Zach466920 that's if you are summing $X_i$ and subtracting $n\mu$. I'm explicitly working with the sample mean.

Comment: @Nitin Thanks, now the mean denotation is fairly obvious, thanks :)

Comment: You're right, it doesn't make sense since the righthand side depends on $n$.

Comment: Indeed it does not make sense because a limit cannot depend on $n$ (and I might have gone as far as explaining this on the site a few times, some of them raising very vocal oppositions).

Comment: @DaveNguyen No. Every random variable is not normal.

Comment: @Did I think dave means that for large n the sample mean has that distribution

Comment: And this is not so in general.

Comment: Isn't that what CLT says though? I guess this is sort of my question

Comment: The CLT says that $Y_n\to N(0,1)$ in distribution, for the random variables $Y_n$ you know. This means that $P(Y_n\leqslant y)\to\Phi(y)$ for every fixed $y$. This says nothing about $P(Y_n\leqslant y_n)$ when $y_n$ depends on $n$.

Comment: Given sequences $Z_n,Y_n$ of random variables, you can't say $Z_n \to Y_n$ in distribution; that doesn't make any sense, because as Did has pointed out, a limit cannot depend on $n$. But it is meaningful to ask about whether $F_{Z_n}(x) - F_{Y_n}(x) \to 0$. Presumably this is the actual question of interest to you (where $Z_n=\overline{X}$ and $Y_n$ is $N(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$).

Comment: @Ian The trouble with this interpretation is that $F_{Z_n}(x)-F_{Y_n}(x)\to0$ for tons of sequences $(Y_n)$, actually for every sequence such that $Y_n\to\mu$ in probability--hence the CLT is quite "lost" with this approach.

Comment: @Did Indeed, it is a weaker statement than that of the CLT. Roughly speaking the formulation of the CLT involves the appropriate renormalization which is required to isolate "finer structure" than the law of large numbers can give. Still, the weaker statement is sensibly defined, whereas the statement in the OP is actually not.

Comment: @Ian I agree--and yet we know for sure this is not what is meant by the statement in this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taken literally, anything that says $\displaystyle\left[\lim_{n\to\infty} (\cdots\cdots) = \text{something depending on }n\right]$ is wrong, as is anything that says $\displaystyle \left[ (\cdots\cdots) \to\text{something depending on }n\text{ as }n\to\infty\right]$.  However, some authors adopt a convention according to which $\displaystyle\left[ (\cdots\cdots) \to N\left( \mu, \frac{\sigma^2} n \right) \right]\text{ as }n\to\infty$ means the same thing as
$$
\frac{\bar X-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt n} \to AN(0,1),
$$
where "$AN$" means "asymptotically normal". The expression $\sigma^2/n$ emphasizes the rate of convergence.

The question says "any sequence of i.i.d. random variables".  That's not quite right: the most usual form assumes they have finite variance.  If they all have the standard Cauchy distribution, for example, then the conclusion is false: the sample mean $\bar X$ still lacks a finite variance, and in fact has the same distribution as does any one of the random variables being averaged.

Someone said in the comments under the question "I guess they just meant $\bar X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$."  That, however, is not correct unless the distibution you start with is normal, and then it's not a limit theorem at all: it's not about what happens as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: In an applied statistics course (i.e. working with nice data and all CLT assumptions are satisfied), is it meaningful to say $\overline{X} \sim N\left(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\right)$ for large $n$?

Comment: @Nitin : One can say that's approximately true for large $n$, and approximately true may be good enough that one can neglect the difference.  One thing that is exact is that the expected value is $\mu$ and the variance is $\sigma^2/n$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: That's obtained by summing the expected values and variances and dividing by n right? I can't believe I didn't see that.

Comment: @Nitin : Correct. ${}\qquad{}$