# Equivalent form of Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

Commonly we use Central Limit Theorem in the following form.

> **Theorem:** Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables such that $E(X_i)=\mu$, $\operatorname{Var}(X_i)=\sigma^2<\infty$. Then,

$$\sqrt{n}\frac{\overline{X}_n-\mu}{\sigma}\stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow}\mathcal{N}(0,1), \tag{1}$$

where $\overline{X}_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.

**I need to show that expression $(1)$ can be replaced by expression $(2)$:**

$$\overline{X}_n - \mu \overset{d}{\longrightarrow}\mathcal{N}(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{n}). \tag{2}$$

---

I tried to use

> **Slutsky theorem**: Let $\{A_n\}$ and $\{B_n\}$ be sequences of random variables. If $A_n \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} A$ and $B_n \overset{P}{\longrightarrow} c$ then $A_n \cdot B_n \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} cA\,$ (and $A_n + B_n \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} A + c$).

If we define $A_n = \sqrt{n}\frac{\overline{X}_n-\mu}{\sigma}, \, B_n = \sigma, \, \forall n$, then by Slutsky theorem we have
$$A_n \cdot B_n = \sqrt{n} (\overline{X}_n-\mu) \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} \sigma \cdot \mathcal{N}(0,1) \equiv \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2). \tag{3}$$

Next, I wanted to show that $(3)$ implies $(2)$. I tried to use Slutsky theorem one more time for sequences $\widetilde{A_n} = \sqrt{n} (\overline{X}_n-\mu), \, \widetilde{B}_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$:
$$\widetilde{A}_n \cdot \widetilde{B}_n = \overline{X}_n-\mu \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} 0 \cdot \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2).$$

As you see, direct usage of the Slutsky theorem give zero as a result because $\widetilde{B}_n \overset{P}{\longrightarrow} 0$.

So how to show correctly that expression $(3)$ implies $(2)$ (or, equivalently, $(1)$ implies $(2)$)?
Maybe it is easier to proof this without using Slutsky theorem?

Comment: What does $\overset{d}{\to} N(0,\sigma^2/n)$ even mean? If $n \to \infty$ then what does the right-hand side mean?

Comment: @angryavian. This is a task from a probability textbook. I am not sure about the meaning of this expression, but I saw it in some sources.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like I found the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1362421/431674). The notation above usually means asymptotic normality of $\sqrt{n} \frac{\overline{X}_n - \mu}{\sigma}$ with rate $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$.

Comment: Then, your notation (2) is *defined* to mean (1).

Comment: @angryavian, yes you are right. I need to ask my teacher about meaning of this strange excercise...